# Self-invocation in Python bottle

Tags: python, http, bottle

Using Python's `bottle` module, I would like to process a request internally, without invoking a call from outside.

Suppose I have the following minimal bottle application running at `localhost:8080` and I would like to invoke `foo` from inside `bar`. One way to do this is:

```
from bottle import *
import requests

@get('/foo')
def foo()
    return 'foo'

@get('/bar')
def bar()
    return requests.get('http://localhost:8080/foo').text

app = default_app()
run(app, port=8080)
```

Now what I would like to do is get rid of the HTTP call using `requests`. I would simply love to use something like:

```
@get('/bar')
def bar()
    return bottle.process_internally('/foo', 'GET')
```

For me, this would have two big advantages:

1. Only single worker is required (the worker is blocked while processing request, hence using `requests.get` leads to deadlock if only one worker is running).
2. No overhead caused by the HTTP protocol.

My true motivation is that I wish to process batches containing request URLs in form of JSON arrays. Very ineffective, yet very fast-to-implement.

Is that somehow possible?

Comment: You could put the stuff you want to do in a different function and call that function in the route handlers.

Comment: Yes, as it said already, just call `return foo()`

Comment: I see your point, but consider I have 100 different API methods. If I want to process a batch that I receive in form of array of URLs (and eventually the POST/GET data), it would be extremely pleasurable to reuse what I already have, just by passing the URLs to ``bottle``.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider "thin controllers" (and skinny everything) paradigm.

With this concept, all your code logic is elsewhere other than the controller (perhaps in your service or model classes).

If you have the bare minimum amount of logic in your controllers, then your `foo` and `bar` routes can call the same functions in your models/services, and you won't need to resort to your routes calling each other.

There are some frameworks that have support for internal redirect (Ruby's Sinatra is one), but I've always considered these a hacky workaround for not writing the code in a flexible way.

Comment: Based on your suggestions, I did some refactoring and made proper distinctions between the model and its controller. Took refactoring of several KLOC though, but thanks for the advice anyway!